# How rewrite this code using promise chaining?

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
function getSmth(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(num * num), 500)
  });
}
function func() {
  getSmth(2).then(res1 => {
    getSmth(3).then(res2 => {
      getSmth(4).then(res3 => {
        console.log(res1 + res2 + res3);
      });
    });
  });
}
   func();
```

```js
function getSmth(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(num * num), 500)
  });
}
function func() {
  getSmth(2)
    .then(res1 => getSmth(3))
    .then(res2 => getSmth(4))
    .then(res3 => {
      console.log(res1 + res2 + res3);
    })
}
func();
```

Should output 29 to the console but it's not work.

Comment: What does not work? Is there an error?

Comment: Read the description

Comment: You said 'but it does not work'. What does not work? Is there an error message? Or do you get the wrong result? How is it that you know it doesn't do what it is supposed to?

Comment: It doesn't output to the console

Comment: `res1` and `res2` are unknown to the last function in the call chain as they are out of scope. Therefore it can't produce an output. Open the browser console and you will see the error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: res1 is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned before me the issue with your chaining is that you are losing the context of the previous result. So you can either use `async/await` or `Promise.all`

Here is the `async/await` syntax which leaves the code more readable

```js
function getSmth(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(num * num), 500)
  });
}

async func(){
  const res1 = await getSmth(2);
  const res2 = await getSmth(3); 
  const res3 = await getSmth(4);
  console.log(res1 + res2 +res3);
}

func().then(()=>{})
```

You can also use `Promise.all` like this

```js
Promise.all([getSmth(2), getSmth(3), getSmth(4)])
.then( results => console.log(results[0] + results[1] + results[2]);
```

Comment: I know but I want to get it right with promise chaining

Comment: You cannot do that since you are losing the scope of each result

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use async/await other answers show the correct code. I think what you might be trying to get is:

```
function func() {
  getSmth(2)
    .then(result => getSmth(3).then(res2 => result + res2))
    .then(result => getSmth(4).then(res3 => result + res3))
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Comment: I can't put you a plus due to reputation